# Android twilio is returning a 500 server error from ngrok

Tags: android, twilio, okhttp, ngrok

I'm using Twilio with Android. Here is my code:

```
private Long sendSMS(String number) {
        Random random = new Random();
        Long verificationCode = (long) random.nextInt((3896 - 298) + 1) + 298;
        try {
            post("http://*******.ngrok.io/sms", new Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "SMS Sent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return verificationCode;
    }
```

And here is the post call:

```
Call post(String url, Callback callback) throws IOException {
    RequestBody formBody = new FormBody.Builder()
            .add("To", "CENSORED_NUMBER")
            .add("Body", "It worked!!!")
            .build();
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(url)
            .post(formBody)
            .build();
    Call response = mClient.newCall(request);
    response.enqueue(callback);
    return response;
}
```

In my backend:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    get("/", (req, res) -> "Hello, World!");
    TwilioRestClient client = new TwilioRestClient("8*******", "******");
    post("/sms", (req, res) -> {
        String body = req.queryParams("Body");
        String to = req.queryParams("To");
        String from = "+17347208686";

        Map<String, String> callParams = new HashMap<>();
        callParams.put("To", to);
        callParams.put("From", from);
        callParams.put("Body", body);
        Sms message = client.getAccount().getSmsFactory().create(callParams);

        return message.getSid();
    });
}
```

Back in ngrok, after trying the above code, I get:

```
    HTTP Requests
-------------

POST /sms                      500 Server Error
```

As you can see, the problem seems to be a 500 Server Error. How can I fix this problem? In the backend, I have my Twilio credentials setup correctly, and the `from` field filled in as: `String from = "+1***2*8*8*";` (Number censored)

I can't find anything in the document saying anything about this error. I can't believe Twilio barely has anything for Android.

Nothing shows up in my logs. So the message wasn't even sent, although the Toast I have in the onResponse method appears.

Comment: "Barely anything for Android"? It's just Java... https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/java/sms/sending-via-rest

Comment: Have you ruled out ngrok as the issue? Can you test your local IP address? Is the issue your REST server's `/sms` handler?

Comment: @cricket_007 actually, no. Take a look here: https://www.twilio.com/blog/2016/05/how-to-send-an-sms-from-android.html I just followed this tutorial

Comment: Sounds like your issue exists in the SparkJava app. Your android code looks fine IMO

Comment: @cricket_007 I'll update my code with my backend

Comment: I am confused how `String number` ever gets to the `post` method...

Comment: @cricket_007 forget about `String number`, I'm putting in my number just to see if it could work.

Comment: Alright, well, set some breakpoints in your server and see what happens.

Comment: @cricket_007 what do you mean set some breakpoints in my server?

Comment: Fire up the debugger in Android Studio / IntelliJ and [set breakpoints and debug](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/tutorial-java-debugging-deep-dive.html)

Comment: @cricket_007 in my backend? Or in my actual application?

Comment: You could do both, I guess, but your backend, where the 500 **internal server error** occurs. Your breakpoint will get hit when a POST is made, and the Android device will probably time-out, but that is fine.

Comment: @cricket_007 thanks, I'm not new to Android, but I am not familiar with all this server stuff. I'll let you know what I get

Comment: You could also use POSTman or cURL to just test your REST endpoint.

Comment: @cricket_007 I'm really not sure what to do. Do I just set a breakpoint in IntelliJ and debug the jar? Not sure what's going on. Could you explain what exactly I do?

Comment: What jar? You just debug the SparkJava program in the main method. Have you read over this link I sent? https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/tutorial-java-debugging-deep-dive.html

Comment: @cricket_007 I know how to debug, at least in Android Studio. That twilio blog told us to run ShadowJar, then run the jar generated. Instead of running the generated jar, do I debug it?

Comment: Yeah, you should be able to just run that `main` method there as-is without Gradle.

Comment: @cricket_007 I get no errors when debugging in IntelliJ

Comment: Did you make the POST request while debugging? Nothing will error if you don't :)

Comment: @cricket_007 how do I do a post request?

Comment: Postman, cURL, call `sendSMS("")` in your app... etc.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135252/discussion-between-abappletic-and-cricket-007).